# Cannot return subclasses of abstract class in implementations of an abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have two sub-classes of an abstract class which each implement an abstract method of their superclass. I want to have a different return type for each, though those return types are in turn sub-classes of a different abstract class. See below:

```
public abstract class Gardener {

    public abstract ArrayList<Flower> getFlowers();
}

public class GardererA extends Gardener {

    public ArrayList<Flower> getFlowers() {
        return new ArrayList<Daisy>();
    }
}

public class GardererB extends Gardener {

    public ArrayList<Flower> getFlowers() {
        return new ArrayList<Rose>();
    }
}

public abstract class Flower {}

public class Daisy extends Flower {}

public class Rose extends Flower {}
```

Obviously Java won't let me do this, but I'm at a loss for how to get this functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: Why have you put `()` in class names? They are not constructor methods.

Comment: I see a lot of classes and not a lot of interfaces. I'd like see to see the client code that need to know the different Gardener A and B. I think generics might help you but we'd need to know some more details.

Comment: @aastefanov thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question to fix that.

Comment: @emeraldjava The code I provided was just an example of the problem, the real code uses abstract classes properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use wildcards:

```
public abstract class Gardener {

    public abstract ArrayList<? extends Flower> getFlowers();

}
```

Comment: this is a great answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use generics like this:

```
public abstract class Gardener<T extends Flower> {

    public abstract ArrayList<T> getFlowers();
}

public class GardererA extends Gardener<Daisy> {

    public ArrayList<Daisy> getFlowers() {
        return new ArrayList<Daisy>();
    }
}

public class GardererB extends Gardener<Rose> {

    public ArrayList<Rose> getFlowers() {
        return new ArrayList<Rose>();
    }
}

public abstract class Flower {}

public class Daisy extends Flower {}

public class Rose extends Flower {}
```